# Can we use Public and Private Access modifier together in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have an expression, I am unable to understand the line of code. So any one can you please explain deeply on this line of code.

public private(set) var items =  [Int] ()

Here

1. Public & Private keyword used together why?
2. Why & where we use (Set) in Swift?

```
public private(set) var items = [Int]()
```

Comment: This syntax is often used as an *objective-c-ish* way to declare a constant. If so don't do that. In Swift there is a native constant.

Answer (score 3):

This property has a public getter and a private setter.

See the [Constants, Variables, Properties, and Subscripts](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html#ID17) section of Access Control in the Swift Programming Language for a full discussion of the syntax.

A quote from the document:

> The structure’s members (including the numberOfEdits property)
> therefore have an internal access level by default. **You can make the
> structure’s numberOfEdits property getter public, and its property
> setter private, by combining the public and private(set) access-level
> modifiers**.

Comment: There is internal getter, not public getter.

Comment: @TrầnHữuHiền I don't quite get what you mean here. The `public` keyword should make this getter public. Why do you believe it would be internal?

Comment: I am sorry, you are right. I have checked document again. Thank you very much!